# Java XML parser using xpath clarification to get the tag value

Tags: java, xml-parsing

i'm new to xml parser using xpath, please help me to extract the tag value for the below xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sync:ApplicationData xsi:schemaLocation="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sync="">
    <sync:FileHeader>
            <sync:FileCreationTimeStamp>2018-12-14T04:15:54.54</sync:FileCreationTimeStamp>
    </sync:FileHeader>
    <sync:CorrespondenceInfo>
        <sync:OrganizationName>
            <sync:OrganizationFullName>GLOBAL PATENTS/RANDY W. TUNG, ESQ </sync:OrganizationFullName>
        </sync:OrganizationName>
        </sync:CorrespondenceInfo>
```

below is my java code to get the `OrganizationFullName`

```
            String filePath = "D:\\cut\\2108.xml";
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));                
            DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(file);
            XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            xmlDocument.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            String name;
            name = xPath.compile("//sync:OrganizationFullName").evaluate(xmlDocument);
            System.out.println(name);
```

while executing getting empty result, Please assist

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the 'sync:' Namespace. To handle this, use this XPath (ignoring the namespace completely):

```
//*[name()='sync:OrganizationFullName']
```

instead. Then the name-variable should be set:

```
"GLOBAL PATENTS/RANDY W. TUNG, ESQ"
```